# How do I use my own custom properties on a KineticJS Sprite?

Tags: html, sprite, kineticjs

I am using the **KineticJS Sprite** object in creation of a simple HTML5 2D canvas game.  I need each sprite to have certain characteristics, such as 'shield', 'firepower', 'speed', etc.  So I need to add my own custom properties to the Sprite object.

Ideally I want something like:

`mySpriteObj.setCustom('shield',50) // set a custom property to 50`

...and then later..

`var shield = mySpriteObj.getCustom('shield') // returns 50`

But there doesn't appear to be anything like that.  I did try to use the attr property (`getAttr` and `setAttr`) with my own custom values but this did not work.

Is there an easy way to associate your own variables with a Sprite object?

thanks
Owen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `getAttr()` and `setAttr()` are the best method to do it, as long as you are not trying to save the canvas using `.toJSON()` and then recreate the node, you can simply assign whatever custom values directly like this:

```
mySpriteObj.shield = someValue;
mySpriteObj.speed = someOtherValue;
var myObjSpeed = mySpriteObj.speed;
var myObjShield = mySpriteObj.shield;
```

Although, you might want to share your code using `getAttr()` and `setAttr()` and try to fix error in that.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the **toJSON()** method will also not **save** those properties

Comment: ohh my bad, actually I wanted to say toJSON and wrote toDataURL. Thnx for pointing it out!!!

Comment: Yes, thank you, it seems to actually work with the above to set the variables and getAttr to retrieve. - but the properties must be added initially when I declare my Sprite objet.

Comment: @Owen, you can set the attribute when you initialize your Sprite. new Kinetic.Sprite({ MyAttr1: attr1, MyAttr2: attr2, ...});

Answer (score 0):

To add a method to a `Kinetic.Shape` you can use the `addMethods` function see the [docs](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Util.html)

You can check the the [Kinetic Source](http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.6.0.js) for examples on how to use this method.

Example:

```
Kinetic.Util.addMethods(Kinetic.Shape, {
  getCustom: function() {
    //getCustom attribute code here
  },
  getCustom2: function() {
    //getCustom attribute code here
  }
});
```

Notice you can add multiple functions by adding more properties (functions) in the object for the second parameter of the `addMethod` function.

And like Ani says, you should use the `getAttr()` and `setAttr()` functions to get and set the custom attributes.

- http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#getAttr
- http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#setAttr

Comment: Thanks, but that's for a Shape, not a Sprite.  Can I use addMethods on a Sprite object too?

Comment: Owen, of course you can. http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Util.html Kinetic.Sprite is a subclass of Kinetic.Shape since KineticJS is OOP. In fact, all the Kinetic "shapes" are subclass to Kinetic.Shape, which is why I used it as an example.